# Why aren't RedBean's transaction functions working?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, redbean

I just noticed that while importing some data to a MySQL database using PHP and RedBean (and a transaction) I could see the number of rows growing while the import was running. To confirm my suspicion I changed the `R::commit()` to `R::rollback()` at the end of the import function and attempted an import. Indeed, the data was imported and permanent even though I called rollback.

I have no idea why the transaction isn't doing it's job and no idea where to start looking, hence this question. [Here's the import part of the function](http://pastebin.com/a1fiZVn5). Let me specify that **apart from the transaction not working** the import function is working great, so there's no need to  dissect it.

Thanks for any and all hypotheses

Comment: What table type are you using in MySQL? Not all of them support transactions, afaik.

Comment: Also, check your query logs (either in RedBean if possible, or at the db end) to ensure a sneaky commit hasn't snuck in somewhere inside a RedBean method.

Comment: All my tables are InnoDB with utf8_unicode_ci collation. Are there any automatic logs I can check or will I have to code that in?

Comment: I've no idea on the RedBean side, but I should think you can turn on query logging in your my.ini - [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AHA! Got it. Eager to prove @furier wrong I looked up the [RedBean transaction documentation](http://www.redbeanphp.com/manual/transactions) and stumbled upon a very helpful note:

> Many databases automatically commit after changing schemas, so make sure you test your transactions after `R::freeze(true);` !

So to summarize, some databases may autocommit if you haven't frozen RedBean using `R::freeze(true);` breaking all transaction action in your application